# XML parsing to display in a view

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, xml-parsing

I am trying to get the data from the individual elements of a XML and display it in a view.

My actual requirement- I receive data in XML format to my application which needs to be displayed in a view for verification.

Right now I have passed the same to the view after loading it in xdocument and in the view I have used linq to access the individual elements. But I feel this is not a proper method to do so in an ASP.Net MVC application.

Also if I can proceed in the same way, how to prevent linq from throwing an error when a particular element is missing from the XML data?

Any suggestions/alternatives would be hugely appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: [w3schools XMLDom](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/) is useful. (at least that's were I learned it)

Comment: @vihan thanks. I am able to access the elements, I needed to know whether this is a proper way to do so in a MVC application where the data is passed from a controller to a view